# iphone search form parameters request and response?

Tags: iphone, parameters, restkit

I'm currently creating a search form which will send a request to the server with multiple parameters from what the user has selected from the search form.

I need to know what would be the best way of sending the data to the server and then receiving a JSON response. I see RestKit can send form data with multiple parameters but isn't this going against the RESTful principle, as you should only do a POST if creating / adding new records?

What is the correct way of doing this so I can send the parameters to a server and then receive JSON back from the server with the results? Is there an API already out there that does this or is RestKit fine for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestKit is fine. ASI is no longer being supported.